# Best way to print every stage of Binary Tree insertion in Python

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I trying to print each stage of a Binary Search Tree after every step of Insertion. However the output generated by my code seems to miss out the initial root data insertion step and also repeats certain stages. I need a clean and easy way to do this. Is there a way to do it using `__dict__.values()`.

**My Code:**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def addNode(self, data):
        if data < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.addNode(data)  # recursively calling addNode method
        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.addNode(data)

        if not self.left is None and not self.right is None:
            print self.left.data, self.data, self.right.data
        elif self.left is None and not self.right is None:
            print None, self.data, self.right.data
        elif not self.left is None and self.right is None:
            print self.left.data, self.data, None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = Node(5)
    #print n.__dict__.values()
    n.addNode(3)
    n.addNode(2)
    n.addNode(8)
    n.addNode(4)
```

**Output Generated:**

```
3 5 None
2 3 None
3 5 None
3 5 8
2 3 4
3 5 8
```

**Expected Output:**

```
None 5 None
3 5 None
2 3 None
3 5 8
2 3 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way you designed this, the printing step is happening on each recursive step, from the inside to the outside. So, for that to make more sense, lets walk through this. You `n.addNode(3)` which gives us

```
3 5 None
```

No surprises. But when you say you expect:

```
2 3 None
```

but get both,

```
2 3 None
3 5 None
```

its because to do `n.addNode(2)` is to examine the first level (`3 5 None`) then to look at the lower level (the node with `data` attribute = `3`). So, printing "from the inside out", we get `2 3 None` (new subtree) then the first level again, `3 5 None`. Its for the same reason that when you expect,

```
2 3 4
```

you instead get,

```
2 3 4
3 5 8
```

The fact that the initial tree (where you expect `None 5 None`) is not printing is a separate issue. It's just because you are initializing the `data` attribute and don't ever get to the printing part because you don't call `addNone`.

A possible solution (that still maintains your structure) would be to only print when you add the node to the tree structure and print the initial subtree manually. Maybe write something like this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def addNode(self, data):
        if data < self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left = Node(data)
                self.printSubtree()
            else:
                self.left.addNode(data)  # recursively calling addNode method
        else:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right = Node(data)
                self.printSubtree()
            else:
                self.right.addNode(data)

    def printSubtree(self):
        if not self.left is None and not self.right is None:
            print self.left.data, self.data, self.right.data
        elif self.left is None and not self.right is None:
            print None, self.data, self.right.data
        elif not self.left is None and self.right is None:
            print self.left.data, self.data, None
        else:
            print None, self.data, None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = Node(5)
    n.printSubtree()
    n.addNode(3)
    n.addNode(2)
    n.addNode(8)
    n.addNode(4)
```

Comment: Thanks! for the valuable input. Is there a possible better method to print them?

Comment: Whatever makes the most sense to you. You can alternatively write a function to print the entire tree structure after you add all the nodes by recursively examining from the root.

Answer (score 0):

1- you printed after adding the nodes, so you can't find an element with None,Number,None as you expect.(so try to move this part before adding the node). 
2- when printing you only considered three possibilities but there is another one, when the left and the right nodes are both None, try adding this.

Comment: I have already tried out what you have suggested!. Doesn't fix my issue.